# How merge git imerge final result to target branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I use git-imerge merge two branches.

```
git checkout branchA
git-imerge start --name=merge-devolp-to-A--first-parent --goal=rebase-with-history develop
```

I ran above command, merge develop branch to branchA.

after merge complete, git-imerge put the final result to a detached HEAD, and I put the HEAD to a new branch.

```
git branch merged ca9d786
```

[image]

these commits makes the whole trace looks mess, I don't think who can understand what is merge x-x.

so what can I do, put the real final merge result to develop branch or branchA with only one commit with nice messages ?

log -

```
$ git-imerge start --name=merge-dev-to-branchA --first-parent --goal=rebase-with-history develop
Checking out files: 100% (9302/9302), done.
Checking out files: 100% (9302/9302), done.
Checking out files: 100% (9302/9302), done.
Checking out files: 100% (9302/9302), done.
Checking out files: 100% (9302/9302), done.
Checking out files: 100% (9272/9272), done.
Checking out files: 100% (9643/9643), done.

Attempting automerge of 7-11...failure.
Attempting automerge of 1-1...success.
Attempting automerge of 1-7...success.
Attempting automerge of 1-10...success.
Attempting automerge of 1-11...success.
Attempting automerge of 7-11...failure.
Attempting automerge of 4-11...failure.
Attempting automerge of 3-11...failure.
Attempting automerge of 2-11...failure.
Attempting automerge of 2-1...success.
Attempting automerge of 2-6...failure.
Attempting automerge of 2-4...failure.
Attempting automerge of 2-3...success.
Attempting automerge of 7-3...success.
Autofilling 1-1...success.
Autofilling 1-2...success.
Autofilling 1-3...success.
Autofilling 1-4...success.
Autofilling 1-5...success.
Autofilling 1-6...success.
Autofilling 1-7...success.
Autofilling 1-8...success.
Autofilling 1-9...success.
Autofilling 1-10...success.
Autofilling 1-11...success.
Recording autofilled block MergeState('merge-dev-to-branchA', tip1='feature/branchA', tip2='develop', goal='rebase-with-history')[0:2,0:12].
Autofilling 2-3...success.
Autofilling 3-3...success.
Autofilling 4-3...success.
Autofilling 5-3...success.
Autofilling 6-3...success.
Autofilling 7-1...success.
Autofilling 7-2...success.
Autofilling 7-3 (first way)...success.
Autofilling 7-3 (second way)...success.
The two ways of autofilling 7-3 agree.
Recording autofilled block MergeState('merge-dev-to-branchA', tip1='feature/branchA', tip2='develop', goal='rebase-with-history')[1:8,0:4].
Attempting automerge of 7-11...success.
Autofilling 2-11...success.
Autofilling 3-11...success.
Autofilling 4-11...success.
Autofilling 5-11...success.
Autofilling 6-11...success.
Autofilling 7-4...success.
Autofilling 7-5...success.
Autofilling 7-6...success.
Autofilling 7-7...success.
Autofilling 7-8...success.
Autofilling 7-9...success.
Autofilling 7-10...success.
Autofilling 7-11 (first way)...success.
Autofilling 7-11 (second way)...success.
The two ways of autofilling 7-11 agree.
Recording autofilled block MergeState('merge-dev-to-branchA', tip1='feature/branchA', tip2='develop', goal='rebase-with-history')[1:8,3:12].
Merge is complete!
```

Comment: It seems there is an error with your image

Comment: please ignore the Uncommitted changes, I am sure the merge is complete.

Comment: Well it's "rebase with merge", I guess this is how its graph should look. You could try another goal to see it nicer.

Comment: But it does not look completed anyway. There should not be those "automatic merge" commits, they should be named after the original commits

Comment: let me try goal=merge

Comment: I tired change goal to merge but have the same result, a lot of commit in a detached HEAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a simple merge as the final result, then you should set `--goal=merge`:

```
git-imerge start --name=merge-develop-to-A --first-parent --goal=merge develop
```

or, more simply,

```
git-imerge merge develop
```

Then, when the imerge is done and you are happy with the result, it is important to type

```
git-imerge finish
```

, which cleans up the intermediate merges and sets your original branch to point at the result.

Comment: git imerge works really good, saved my life. I have one question, why the merge tool not become to a part of git ?